# Parse dates in format dmY together with mdY using strptime in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, date-formatting

I want to convert the input date string into format => '%Y%m%d'.
I am using Python 3.x and trying this with the help strptime & strftime.

The problem is that my input date string can be either in '%m%d%Y' or '%d%m%Y' format.
How does my logic know if the starting position is a day or month?

```
date_formats = ['%m/%d/%Y','%d/%m/%Y']

def get_date_in_ymd_format(input_date):
    for date_format in date_formats:
        try:
            #convert string to date object: convert input_date string given format date_formate (if format does not match throw exception)
            date_in_ymd = datetime.strptime(input_date, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        date_in_ymd = None
    return date_in_ymd
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't know.  There will be some dates that are obviously one or the other (a 13 cannot be a month value, for example), but plenty of dates that are ambiguous:

```
01/02/2020
```

can be either January 2 of February 1.